# Excluir estoque diretamente do botão Jquery

Tags: jquery

Como eu faço para que ao clicar no botão remover e ativar a função removerCampo(), seja chamada a página que faria essa exclusão diretamente da base de dados mysql? Preciso apenas da parte do Jquery para isso, pois o PHP e Mysql eu sei fazer. Vejam abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou trazendo essas informações do banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
....
while($jmTamanhos = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){
      $visualizar .=  "<tr class='linhas'>
         <td  style=\"padding: 5px\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"Cores[]\" class=\"tamanhos form-control\" placeholder=\"Cor do Produto\" value='".$jmTamanhos->Cores."'></td>
         <td  style=\"padding: 5px\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"Tamanho[]\" class=\"form-control pull-left\" placeholder=\"Tamanho\" value='".$jmTamanhos->Tamanho."'></td>
         <td  style=\"padding: 5px\"><input type=\"number\" name=\"EstoqueProd[]\" class=\"form-control pull-left\" placeholder=\"Estoque\" min=\"1\" value='".$jmTamanhos->Estoque."'></td>
         <td  style=\"padding: 5px\">
         <input type='hidden' name='IDEstoques[]' value='".$jmTamanhos->IDEstoques."'>
         <button type=\"button\" class=\"removerCampo btn btn-danger\" title=\"Remover linha\"><i class=\"fa fa-minus-square\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> Remover</button>
         </td>
       </tr>";
}
$visualizar .= " <tr><td colspan=\"3\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"adicionarCampo btn btn-primary\" title=\"Adicionar item\"><i class=\"fa fa-plus-square\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> Adicionar mais tamanhos</button></td></tr>";
....
```

E o Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    removeCampo();
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }
  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
        novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
      novoCampo.find('select').val("");
      novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
      removeCampo();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Não faz. O JavaScript roda no browser e é impossível acessar a base de dados diretamente por ele (ainda bem!). Você vai ter que fazer uma requisição HTTP e tratar a deleção no servidor com a linguagem dele (aparentemente é PHP)

Comment: Olá LINQ, na verdade não é excluir os dados pelo javascript ou jquery, mas sim que ao clicar no botão e ativar a função removerCampo(), seja chamada a página que faria essa exclusão, que no caso está em PHP.

Comment: Olá LINQ, ajustei meu post. Desculpe, não havia sido claro na minha dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra isso você vai precisar fazer uma requisição `http` para um arquivo `php` que contenha a `query` que ira exluir. Quem realmente `excluir` é o `php`, o `ajax` vai ser responsavel apenas por enviar a requisição (e um `id` para excluir o correto).

Um exemplo de como isso funcionaria é:

```
<button data-id="1" class="excluir">Excluir</button>
```

Como o seu `button` é adicionado com o `while` você pode passar o `id` no `data-id`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.excluir', function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'seuArquivo.Php',
       data: {id: $(this).attr('data-id')},
       success: function(data){
          alert('excluido')
          removeCampo()
       }
    })
})
```

O `ajax` vai passar o seu `id` via metodo `POST` para o arquivo php, então o `php` ficaria mais ou menos assim.

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id = ?");
$sql->execute(array($_POST['id']))
```

Com isso você já conseguiria excluir um registro do banco de dados ao apertar o botão `excluir`.
Existe varias formas de fazer isso, só dei um exemplo.

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado Rafael. Funcionou!